# is there a way to catch if a user confirm/abort the access to navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps, w3c

I have a standard call to the geolocation api on my web application :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation);
```

Well, a user press OK on his device (so, he confirm the access for sharing data).

If the location is found trought the GPS the function `foundLocation` is called; else, it calls `noLocation`.

What I need is to check if a user have pressed OK (at the beginning) or he have aborted the sharing data with GPS.

How can I catch that event? Hope the question is clear more or less...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the first argument gets called in case you press OK and the second if you press Cancel (or a button with some text that looks like that).

Comment: No! The first argument is called if, after press OK, it found coordinate. The second argument is called if, after press OK, it doesnt found coordinate. What I need is check if a user press OK :)

Comment: Are you sure? If I run this on Chrome and press Cancel, the second argument gets called.

Comment: ??? Really? Tried on IE/Chrome/Firefox and it doesnt call the second argument. Can you post your example code? So I'll check...

Comment: Oh yeah, in fact you are right. On chrome it works, but not on mozilla...uhm... I should check on a real GPS device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as specified by http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html

```
// Request a position. We accept positions whose age is not
// greater than 10 minutes. If the user agent does not have a
// fresh enough cached position object, it will automatically
// acquire a new one.
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {maximumAge:600000});

function successCallback(position) {
  // By using the 'maximumAge' option above, the position
  // object is guaranteed to be at most 10 minutes old.
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    // Update a div element with error.message.
    if (error == 1) {
        alert('no location provided');
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Seems to be a bug within mozilla https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533. Not sure if they will fix this?

Comment: yes, but if you try http://jsfiddle.net/2DHFZ/ on firefox (and you abort, clicking like on X) you won't see the alert..(so the errorCallback is not called...)

Comment: Oh... I see! Well, hope it will works on smartphones (this is my target)... I will check... thanks